# how will pig generate DAG of jobs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am processing a feed to millions of records using PIG. After reading the feed from HDFS, i need to perform three different 'group by' operation and then union the results of all of them. lets say regardless of the schema of the relation union works well. Now my question is how PIG generates the DAG of execution and does all these three group by operation will be performed in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pig's processing steps are as follows:

1. Script parsing

   - check syntax and whether referenced variables are valid
   - type checking
   - schema inference
   - check custom classes (UDFs) (instantiation..etc)

Output: a canonical logical plan which is a one-to-one mapping between the pig latin statements and the logical operator, arranged in the form of a DAG.

2. Logical optimizer

   - the logical plan is passed through a logical optimizer (e.g: projection pushdown is 
     carried out)
3. Physical plan

   - the optimized logical plan is translated to a physical plan. (Each logical operator has a corresponding physical equivalence)
4. MapReduce plan and its optimization

   - Each physical operator will be assigned to a MapReduce stage (Map task or Reduce task).
   - After the MR plan is created further optimizations are performed based on the nature of the operations. Goal: minimize the number of reduce stages

You can check the generated plans for you PIG script with [EXPLAIN](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/test.html#explain)

For your second question:
 
The group by operation forces a reduce phase for which you can define the *level of parallelism*. By default, if no parallelism is specified, the number of reducers are
calculated by this formula:

```
min(maxReducersNumber, reducers)
```

where:
- maxReducersNumber can be set by the property pig.exec.reducers.max (default 999) 
- reducers = (totalInputFileSize / bytesPerReducer) 
- bytesPerReducer can be set by the property pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer (default: 1GB) I.e: for every 1GB of input data Pig will allocate a new reducer

More information about parallel can be found here:
 - [how to use the parallel feature](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/perf.html#parallel)
- [select the right level of parallelism](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch08.html#setting_parallel)
- [source code of the reducer estimator](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/InputSizeReducerEstimator.java)